# Breaking an input into words to work on one by one (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I'm trying to implement a java program which, given a string with linebreaks as input through a simple graphical interface, splits it first at lines, then at spaces, and then for each word has an instruction that tells it what to do with it. I got to something like this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author michelegorini
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HakkaTranslator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HakkaTranslator
     */
    public HakkaTranslator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        inputField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        translateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pinyinField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hakkaCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mandCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        translateButton.setText("Translate");
        translateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                translateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(mandCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(translateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(translateButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mandCharField))
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void translateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Scanner kLFeed = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*\n\\s*");
        Scanner kSp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String kSpInput;
        do{
            kSpInput = kLFeed.next();
            while(kSp.hasNext(kSpInput)){
                translate(kSp.next(kSpInput));
            }
            translate("\n");
        } while(kLFeed.hasNext());
    }                                               

    private void translate(String word){
        pinyinField.setText(pinyinField.getText() + word);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HakkaTranslator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel hakkaCharField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inputField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mandCharField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pinyinField;
    private javax.swing.JButton translateButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Now most of this is auto-generated by the NetBeams IDE. All I actually typed was:

```
    private void translateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Scanner kLFeed = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*\n\\s*");
        Scanner kSp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String kSpInput;
        do{
            kSpInput = kLFeed.next();
            while(kSp.hasNext(kSpInput)){
                translate(kSp.next(kSpInput));
            }
            translate("\n");
        } while(kLFeed.hasNext());
    }                                               

    private void translate(String word){
        pinyinField.setText(pinyinField.getText() + word);
    }
```

save for the `translateButtonActionPerformed` method opening. Now when I run this, whatever I type in the text field (i.e. with "kin-ha \n"), the program invariably blocks. Is it that I have a slow computer or is there a problem in the code? Perhaps the `useDelimiter` is wrongly written? I am new to that method. By the way, how do I get a linebreak into that interface? Pressing the return key does nothing.

Comment: `System.in` is the "standard input" (the console, "Command Prompt" window, etc. depending on your OS).  If you're typing input into a text field in a GUI, `System.in` will never see it.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes. Note that I've only just started designing GUIs, I'm `NetBeans`-dependent, I have little or no idea what the GUI code is doing. So how do I have the scanner see the text from the GUI text field?

Comment: `Scanner` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) that takes a `String` as a source.  You'll have to extract the `String` from the text field.  This might be `inputField.getText()`, but I'm not sure and I don't want to study all your code.

Comment: I'll see what happens when I try that. Now the.other problem is that I'd like to give it linebreaks in the input, but the return key does nothing when typing in the input field. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you'll need to ask a new StackOverflow question...

Comment: Yep, inputField.getText() as the input works. So I'll ask a new question for the linebreaks.