# Linebreak in text inputted through GUI

Tags: java, swing, input, graphics, interface

I'm trying to build a program that, through a GUI, receives input text with linebreaks, splits it at lines, then at spaces, and for each string does something "special". The problems are 2:

1. I can't get linebreaks into the input field;
2. I don't know how to get the linebreaks into the output.

How do I do that? My code is:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author michelegorini
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HakkaTranslator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HakkaTranslator
     */
    public HakkaTranslator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        inputField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        translateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pinyinField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hakkaCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mandCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        translateButton.setText("Translate");
        translateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                translateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(mandCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(translateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(translateButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mandCharField))
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void translateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Scanner kLFeed = new Scanner(inputField.getText()).useDelimiter("\n");
        Scanner kSp;
        do{
            kSp = new Scanner(kLFeed.next());
            while(kSp.hasNext()){
                translate(kSp.next());
            }
            translate("<br/>");
        } while(kLFeed.hasNext());
    }                                               

    private void translate(String word) {
        pinyinField.setText(pinyinField.getText() + word);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HakkaTranslator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel hakkaCharField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inputField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mandCharField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pinyinField;
    private javax.swing.JButton translateButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

at the moment.

**Update:**
Taking the answer and comments into account, I came to:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author michelegorini
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HakkaTranslator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HakkaTranslator
     */
    public HakkaTranslator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        inputField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        translateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pinyinField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hakkaCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mandCharField = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        translateButton.setText("Translate");
        translateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

                inpText = inputField.getText();
                String[] lines = inpText.split(System.lineSeparator());
                String[][] words = new String[lines.length][20];
                for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                    words[i] = lines[i].split(" ");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                    for(int j = 0;j<words[i].length;j++){
                        translate(words[i][j]);
                    }
                    translate(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(mandCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(translateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(translateButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(pinyinField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(inputField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(hakkaCharField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mandCharField))
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void translate(String word) {
        pinyinField.setText(pinyinField.getText() + word + " ");
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HakkaTranslator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JLabel hakkaCharField;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea inputField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mandCharField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pinyinField;
    private javax.swing.JButton translateButton;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    String inpText;
}
```

One problem persists: even with `System.lineSeparator()`, the linebreaks in the output just won't appear. How do I solve that? And how do I avoid having `javax.swing` every time?

Comment: Why are you using a textfield and not a textarea?

Comment: Uhmmm… I don't really know the difference :). The code is mostly auto-generated by NetBeams, my knowledge of java GUI is… well… less than basic probably :).

Comment: A Textfield is a one line Text as i know. Only a TextArea can have more than one line.

Comment: OK, I've tried changing every `TextField` to `TextArea`, but the return key still does nothing :(.

Comment: And inputting a very long string causes … to appear in the output.

Comment: @Jens `JTextArea`, `JTextPane` and `JTextEditor` all support multiline text. As you said, the various text fields do not - pressing Enter calls the action of the text field.

Comment: The Enter key in a `JTextArea` creates a new line. Post the relevant code.

Comment: OK, now the problem was I had a project with a name, and I had different versions under the same project, and by pressing the `Run` button in the IDE I thought I was loading the most recent one, the one I was viewing just before pressing the button. Apparently I wasn't, so I was stuck with a field instead of an area. The input linebreak problem vanished as soon as I loaded the right version by compiling and loading the class with Terminal, i.e. outside that misleading IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how to read the text of a text area to a string.

```
public class GetterText extends JFrame {

    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    String taText;

    GetterText() {

        JButton getText = new JButton("GetText");
        getText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                taText = ta.getText();
                System.out.println(taText);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(getText, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GetterText();
    }
}
```

You can use `taText.split(" ")` to split around spaces and `taText.split("\\n")` to split around lines.

Comment: Uhmmm… `cannot find symbol symbol class JFrame`… maybe javax.swing.JFrame? And so for all other GUI classes.

Comment: But withot `awt` I can't type `javax.awt.event.ActionListener`, and I know no other way that works here to create an `ActionListener`, since simply putting `ActionListener` gives `cannot find symbol` just like `JFrame`, so… what do I do?

Comment: @MickG There is only one `JFrame` - the one you stated. Your GUI builder writes fully qualified names. I suggest you write your own GUIs and not use a builder. Use an import instead of writing the fully qualified name in the code.

Comment: @MickG I said use Swing components instead of AWT ones. The events are shared between AWT and Swing (which builds on AWT).

Comment: In any case I've found a way to make things work with `awt`. One last thing: how do I print a linebreak? Because having it ad `"\n"` to the `pinyinField` only prints a wide space.

Comment: @MickG "I've found a way to make things work with awt" This is bad, don't do it. By the way, all the code you posted is Swing, so I don't know why you bring up AWT. Whoever told you to use `TextArea` instead of `JTextArea` gave you bad advice.

Comment: @MickG Replace `\n` with `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: Nobody did and I'm using `JTextArea`. Why I bring up `awt`… I am not bringing it up, it's `NetBeans` doing it. The GUI code is practically entirely generated by that IDE.

Comment: @MickG Good, then you are not using AWT. :)

Comment: And to import as you suggest, what should I type? `import javax.swing` gives `package javax does not exist`, and `import java.swing` gives `cannot find symbol`, at least compiling on Terminal.

Comment: @MickG Add the line `import javax.swing.JFrame;`.

Comment: as for `not use a builder`, I am simply unable to build a GUI without a builder. I started using GUIs like… yesterday :). 2-3 days ago actually, so I really can't do without that builder. Most of the code looks like Old Teutonic to me (I can't say "Greek" because I understand it :)). If I go on with this long enough to learn how to write my own GUIs, then I will abandon NetBeans.

Comment: @MickG NetBeans contains a GUI builder. You don't have to abandon NetBeans all together, just the GUI builder in it.

Comment: See the update. The code given there doesn't use the `imports`, but the result is the same: the linebreaks in the output do not appear.

Comment: @MickG Try using [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html).

Comment: From what I've read, `BreakIterator` seems to be a good, probably better, way to break the input. But what does it have to do with the linebreaks-in-the-output problem?

Comment: @MickG You have too many different problems in one question. Ask different questions for different problems. Don't forget to prvite a working code, input, and output, that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that: I've been banned from asking questions :(.

Comment: @MickG You need to read on how to ask questions on SO. Since I answered here about getting text from the text area, I suggest you slightly edit your [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816019/breaking-an-input-into-words-to-work-on-one-by-one-java) to ask about splitting the text. You asked more or less the same 2 questions on 2 posts (bad) instead of 1 on each.